# Sending expiry notification for Apple wallet pass

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, wallet, apple-wallet

I'm trying to build a store card type pass for Apple Wallet. I want to send push notification to the user sometime before the pass expires. Is there a field apple provides that i can set in the pass.json to send the notification or is there any other way?

Comment: Blast! Saw this and thought I might find my own answers, but nothing yet. In the last 24 hours I've discovered dotnet-passbook by Tomas McGuinness for creating the pass, and dotAPNS for sending notifications, and a really badly written other article about managing subscribers, but I can't quite find the glue. I am also trying to push an APNS to trigger a pass update (and ideally show a message!)

Comment: That seem to be the only way to send notifications. I was expecting a straight forward way to send a standard expiry notification(google has it). Sending an update to the pass before expiry for it to show expiry notification seems like a bad solution for this use-case.

Comment: I kinda got mine to work, except that when it's firing the "get the updates for my pass" web service the example code returns a different return type to the endpoint where I made the original pass. 

Did you get it to show a notification for the user?

Comment: Yes. We had to go with the whole APN implementation route. Wish they had an easier way to sent some standard notification like pass expiry. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/walletpasses/adding_a_web_service_to_update_passes#:~:text=the%20updated%20pass.-,Send%20a%20Push%20Notification,-Send%20a%20push